# Why is my JavaFX Tableview not editable?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Why is my TableView not allowing the ID column to be editable? The `getPenaltyIdProperty()` returns an IntegerProperty (a SimpleIntegerProperty to be exact) and yet I thought this would allow the edits to happen automatically via bindings. what am I missing?

```
public class PenaltyDashboardManager { 

    private final TableView<Penalty> penaltyTable = new TableView<Penalty>();

/* ... */

    private void initializeTable() { 

        penaltyTable.setItems(Penalty.getPenaltyManager().getPenalties());
        penaltyTable.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Penalty,Number> penaltyId = new TableColumn<>("ID");
        penaltyId.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().getPenaltyIdProperty());
        penaltyId.setEditable(true);

        /* ... */

        penaltyTable.getColumns.add(penaltyId);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you set the `cellFactory` somewhere? (Also, can you fix the class names and variable names in your posted code so they are consistent: `StratPenalty`/`Penalty`? `penaltyId`/`stratTableId`?)

Comment: Ah I was dumbing down the naming conventions for this post. I'll fix that.

Comment: Let me explore the cellFactory, but the edit binding just doesn't happen? I thought that was the whole point of the Property interface...

Comment: The edit binding happens (i.e. the binding between the control in the cell and the model property), but you need a cell that allows the user to perform an edit. The default cell effectively just displays a label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a cell factory to produce a cell that allows the user to edit the value. E.g.

```
penaltyId.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new NumberStringConverter());
```

Comment: `NumberStringConverter` to bridge the view to the model... JavaFX team really did think of everything.